# undeclared (first use in this function) in C

Tags: c

I know when you type this into search, there are a few similar "like" questions. Yet, all the ones I saw that weren't duplicate were from other sources besides C. Anyway, hope someone can help.
I have a structure, declared in my header obviously.

```
struct Statistics //Super basic structure.
{
 int mean;
 int median;
 int variance;
 int grades;
 int min;
 int max;
};
```

All of these functions are working properly without the structure, that's why I'm trying to use one. For cleanliness, and just pure understanding.
My error is this, I get the line **'stats' undeclared (first use in this function)** when I call the function this structure is within.

This is where the error send me to:

```
display_grades_distribution(m, grades_scale,n, stats);
```

So my question is this, how could my compiler tell me that this structure is 'undeclared' and or that its the 'first use' in the program.

SNIPPET:

```
void display_grades_distribution(int m, int grades_scale[11][m], int n,         
struct Statistics stats[])
{
 printf("Mean = %22f\n", stats[0].mean);
 printf("Variance = %18f\n", stats[0].variance);
 printf("Median = %20f\n", stats[0].median);
 printf("min = %16d\n", stats[0].min);
 printf("max = %16d\n", stats[0].max);
}

int main(void)
{
 //-------------------------------------------
  for(m = 0, m < num_assignments; m++)
  {
  struct Statistics stats[5];
  stats[m].mean = calculate_mean(grades,n);
  stats[m].median = calculate_median(grades,n);
  stats[m].variance = calculate_mean(grades,n);
  stats[m].min = calculate_min(grades,n);
  stats[m].max = calculate_max(grades,n);
  }
 //-------------------------------------------
 **display_grades_distribution(m, grades_scale,n, stats);** //This causes the error.
}
```

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. The error is [not reproduced](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SgRrzNCgEVqysrn7).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Stop thinking such a wrong thing and try [compiling](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HQEnHAjYRbkZpzto).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - being diplomatic, you are confusing the case where a `typedef` was used with `Statistics` earlier.

Comment: Your declaration is limited to the *scope* of the `for` loop. Move `struct Statistics stats[5];` outside the `for`. `display_grades_distribution` has no idea what `stats` is.

Comment: I tried to reduce it alot, like the site said. As simple as possible.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you declare the array before the `for` loop?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin , is there anyway to enlarge the scope of 'stats' to where display function can call it?

Comment: Yes, you simply move the declaration *outside* the `for` block as MikeCAT shows in his answer.

Comment: Adding `**` to where they shouldn't be will lead to compile error.

Comment: @DancingDylan - when you declare a variable *inside* a `for` block (or any block of code for that matter), it is only visible *inside* that block of code. That is the basic rule of *scope*. To make `stats` visible to everything in `main`, it must be declared in `main`, but not inside any other block of code that itself is within `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct Statistics stats[5];` is local variable in the block used in `for` statement, so it isn't visible after the `for` loop.

Get it out of `for` statement.

```
int main(void)
{
  struct Statistics stats[5];
  //-------------------------------------------
  for(m = 0, m < num_assignments; m++)
  {
    stats[m].mean = calculate_mean(grades,n);
    stats[m].median = calculate_median(grades,n);
    stats[m].variance = calculate_mean(grades,n);
    stats[m].min = calculate_min(grades,n);
    stats[m].max = calculate_max(grades,n);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------
  display_grades_distribution(m, grades_scale,n, stats);
}
```